# Make VMWare to connect through Proxy System Settings

Tags: http, proxy, vmware

I have installed VMWare Workstation on windows 7.

I have a virtual machine and I'm trying to set it to use proxy system settings.

Finally when I use virtual machine I want to have assigned ip from Lan Settings >> Proxy from windows 7.
How can I do this?

PS: I've already tried vinlogu and not works.